# How to close a dropdown after the mouseout for 1 sec of two element?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have this situation where I have 2 dropdown which is pretty much looks like and I want this:

[image: What I want]

1. When we hover on item 5, dropdown B will appear
2. When we mouseout from item 5 there will be a timeout (1-2) second to trigger a function to hide dropdown B
3. But if within the timeout we mouseover to dropdown B then the timeout will be reset and dropdown B will not be hidden

I tried these condition, where `#nested` is the id of **item 5** and **#dropdown2** is the **dropdown B**

```js
var closeNestedDropdown = function(){
    $('#dropdown2').hide();
}

$('#nested,#dropdown2').on('mouseover', function(e){
    $('#dropdown2').show();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});

$('#nested,#dropdown2').on('mouseout', function(e){
     timeout = setTimeout(closeNestedDropdown, 1000);
});
```

Or please refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/machun/oeb5fmy4/1/), I have tried some ways but none works yet, can't figure out an idea how to do that.

Comment: is this you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/oeb5fmy4/6/

Comment: are the children applied the same event as it's parent? wow cool, didn't know that before XD. do you want to put that as an answer? i will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var closeNestedDropdown = function(){
    $('#dropdown2').hide();
}

$('#nested').on('mouseover', function(e){ //remove the #dropdown2
    $('#dropdown2').show();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});

$('#nested').on('mouseout', function(e){ //remove the #dropdown2
     timeout = setTimeout(closeNestedDropdown, 1000);
});
```